# Getting ExecuteExcel4Macro to Recognise Empty Cells

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-4.0

When I use the ExecuteExcel4Macro function in a VBA script like so:

```
Public Function GetNamedData(Path, File, Address)
  Dim Data As String
  Data = "'" & Path & File & "'!" & Address
  GetNamedData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data)  
End Function
```

Where `Address` is a named range in my case, if the cell in the closed workbook is *empty*, this function returns *0*. But some cells contain (deliberately) *0*.

How do I differentiate between *empty* cells and cells containing *0*?

To explain further, I am using this function to get data from a closed workbook. This has proven very fast at collecting lots of data from closed workbooks.

I understand there are differences between '0' and empty, but I am not sure how to work it into this function.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the helpful response. I have tried to research and cannot find much useful, hence why I am now asking here.

@ Peh I am using the ExecuteExcel4Macro to grab data from a closed workbook (without opening it). I only just learnt about this function recently and it has made my data retrieval so much faster. If there is a better way, please do let me know.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the input. I am still not making the connection though. I understand what you are saying about how the ExecuteExcel4Macro works...but if all it returns is '0' how do I know whether it was actually a '0' or an empty cell, as they both produce the same result?

Comment: @Peh looks like Jeeped comments disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
GetNamedData = ExecuteExcel4Macro("IF(COUNTA(" & Data & ")," & Data & ",""X"")")
```

Then GetNamedData = "X" in case the cell in closed workbook is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The below function adds a "" (Null) the the value and so the GetValue2 function returns a null if empty or a zero if it is a zero.

```
Function GetValue2(strPath As String, strFilename As String, strTabName As String, intColumnNumber As Integer, intRowNumber As Integer) As String
  Dim varCellValue As Variant
  Dim strContents As String

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  varCellValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & strPath & "[" & strFilename & "]" & strTabName & "'!R" & intRowNumber & "C" & intColumnNumber & " & """"")
  strContents = CStr(varCellValue)
  GoTo NiceExit
ErrHandler:
  Call MsgBox("strPathFilename : " & strPath & strFilename & Chr(13) & _
           "strTabName      : " & strTabName & Chr(13) & _
           "intColumnNumber : " & intColumnNumber & Chr(13) & _
    "") ' & Error.msg, vbOKOnly)
NiceExit:
  GetValue2 = strContents
End Function
```

Comment: varCellValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & strPath & "[" & strFilename & "]" & strTabName & "'!R" & intRowNumber & "C" & intColumnNumber & " & """"")